# How to switch between aws accounts in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'am creating a Jenkins job using activeChoiseParam plugin.
My problem is how to dynamically switch between aws accounts depending on choise(development, pre-prod) and get kubernetes namespaces from selected account.
I tried to use withAWS in script parameter but It doesn't support.
My parameters:

```
properties([
  parameters([
    choice(name: "CLUSTER_NAME", choices: ["development", "pre-prod"], description: "Cluster for deploying"),
    [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
     choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
     description: 'Select the Server from the Dropdown List',
     filterLength: 1,
     filterable: true,
     name: 'Server',
     randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314456178619',
     referencedParameters: 'CLUSTER_NAME',
     script: [
       $class: 'GroovyScript',
       fallbackScript: [
         classpath: [],
         sandbox: false,
         script:
           'return[\'Could not get Environment from Env Param\']'
       ],
       script: [
         classpath: [],
         sandbox: false,
         script:
           ''' if (CLUSTER_NAME.equals("development")){
                                def getNamespaces = "kubectl get namespaces -o jsonpath={.items[*].metadata.name}"
                                def devNamespaces = getNamespaces.execute().in.text.split().toList()
                                return devNamespaces
                            }
                            else if(CLUSTER_NAME.equals("pre-prod")){
                                def getNamespaces = "kubectl get namespaces -o jsonpath={.items[*].metadata.name}"
                                def preProdNamespaces =getNamespaces.execute().in.text.split().toList()
                                return preProdNamespaces
                                }
                        '''
       ]
     ]
    ]
  ])
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your credentials in jenkins using 'CloudBees AWS Credentials' plugin

then in your pipeline use 'withCredentials' to refers to the previously created aws credential.

ex:

```
    stage("xxxxxxx") {

    withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
        accessKeyVariable: 'aKV',
        secretKeyVariable: 'sKV',
        credentialsId: 'id_of_your_credential',
    ]]) {
            sh '''
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${aKV}\
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${sKV}\
            AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1\
            aws ec2 describe-images        
            '''
    }
}
```

- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ... are shell environment variables for aws-cli.

I'm not sure about what you exactly need but you get the idea.